# Extract data from Text

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have this text:

```
{
   "id": "my id",
   "name": "name",
   "first_name": "first name",
   "last_name": "last name",
   "username": "nick",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_EN"
}
```

how to insert the ID, name, and other in textbox?

thanks for your answer

Comment: Deserialize this JSON into an object and then set the textbox `.Text` property to the appropriate property of that object

Comment: thanks but I do not know c#, but I will do this little application

Comment: Looks at [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) in order to turn JSON data into .NET objects.

Comment: and if this text is already in a textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go [here](http://json.codeplex.com/) and download JSON.Net. In archive find proper version of DLL and add reference to this DLL into your C# project.
After that you can do such way:

```
string json = @"{
                 'id': 'my id',
                 'name': 'name',
                 'first_name': 'first name',
                 'last_name': 'last name',
                 'username': 'nick',
                 'gender': 'male',
                 'locale': 'en_EN'
                }";

JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

textBoxID.Text = obj["id"].ToString();
textBoxName.Text = obj["name"].ToString();
//and so on
```